# Finding specific words/combination in a continuous String in python

Tags: python

So I'm curious, how do I find specific combination of word in a continuous string?

I'm really new to python and here's the simplest code I've written.

```
#find amount of bob(s) in the string
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
count = 0
for letter in s:
    if letter == 'bob':
        count += 1

print count
```

The count works fine if letter == '*a single letter*', but it won't count the amount of "bob"s that appears in the continuous string (which in this case is 2).

Comment: @Delgan: That won't work, since the OP wants to allow overlapping matches.

Comment: @PM2Ring are you sure? Where does he say that?

Comment: Sorry, then, I read to fast.

Comment: @timgeb: He expects a count of 2 for the sample data `azcbobobegghakl'`

Comment: @timgeb: Nice dupe target; it's even got the same test data. :) Pity neither of those questions have timeit speed tests on the various approaches, but I _suspect_ that the `str.find`-based approaches won't be faster than using regex.